# Chrome Extension communicating with dev server

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way I can have a Python server send messages to a chrome extension, whether it be the content or background script?

I have a Python script making network requests that needs some cookies stored in my browser. I was trying to find a way to have the Python script send a message to the extension to refresh the page to get new cookies & send them back to the script.

Comment: I've never used it, but it seems you might be able to setup a socket connection to your python server using chrome.socket. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket

Comment: this is interesting! thank you. I'll look into this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/

Comment: Chrome extensions aren't chrome apps so extensions can't use chrome.socket API. What you need is probably [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: can you put this as the answer so I can mark it as correct. You sir, thank you!!!